# Ошибка при старте dhcp сервера

Tags: linux, сеть, virtualbox, kali-linux, dhcp

Установлена последняя версия kali-linux на виртуалке.
При использовании команды `sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart` получаю ошибку `Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`
Вот вывод `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service`:
[image: error1]

Вот вывод:`journalctl -xn`
[image: error2]

Линуксом недавно пользуюсь, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Скорей всего, dhcpd просто не настроен (чаще всего, пара интерфейс-адреса, плюс прописаны не все или лишние интерфейсы относительно /etc/default/*dhcp*). Посмотрите логи, там детальнее. P.S. Kali — это точно не для "недавно пользуюсь", имейте в виду.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev я понимаю, что не для недавно, но интересно попробовать инструментарий данной системы, вот и разбираюсь. В файле /etc/default/*dhcp*/ следующее - https://imgur.com/nVJWPsb . Так же добавил в файл /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf данную строчку - `[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` вместо x mac адаптера, результат не изменился, помогите настроить правильно, пожалуйста

Comment: Судя по логам, написано, что ошибка в том, что файл /var/run/dhcpd.pid уже существует
https://imgur.com/wP1Rb8U